# Best way of generating workload for personal cloud storage

Tags: automated-testing, performance, system-testing, files

I'm currently working on a folder synchronization tool which synchronizes the content of a specific folder with a remote cloud storage provider.

In order to test the robustness of the client, I need a tool which generates random (but repeatable) file system operations (create file, modify file, delete file/folder, move file/folder, rename file/folder, etc.) in a way as similar as possible to the behavior of a real user.

The first idea that came to my mind was to create such a tool on my own. However, I'm wondering if I can find something that can make me save some time.

Do you know any tool like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try vdbench, it is very flexible and powerful. There are many other file system load generators each with its own ups and downs and with different features, try googling for them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following tools as per your given requirements:

1 - Selenium IDE , Selenium web driver - For functionality testing.

2 - Jmeter - For Load / Stress testing

Using selenium web driver you can create script as you mentioned like create file , folder , rename , modify and a lot ,ore.

Jmeter will help you to measure capacity of your system/site.

Helpful links :

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

http://jmeter.apache.org/

http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/

If you want to put load of 500+ real user then you will have to use some good cloud base solution like : **http://blazemeter.com/**

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hi Helping Hands, maybe I'm mistaken but selenium seems to be a automation tool meant for web browsers, while I'm looking for a tool which generates activity on the local file system. So it has nothing to do with web browsers.

Comment: @pAkY88 - Ahh ok..You did not specify that so I thought that it is related to web.